# Reclassifying certain values using ArcPy in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcpy, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator, arcgis-pro, reclassify

I need to reclassify certain values to different values in a raster using Python in ArcGIS Pro 2.2.2. I can't use reclassify because I don't want to change all values and I can't go through each one of them because there is a lot. When I use Raster calculator I get an attribute error.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this approach Esri provide for ArcGIS Pro [Reclassify](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/reclassify.htm)

> Reclassifies (or changes) the values in a raster.

I would suggest using the code samples they provide as guidance as to how you can build your python code to reclassify the values in your raster

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env  
from arcpy.sa import *
env.workspace = "C:/sapyexamples/data"

outReclass1 = Reclassify("landuse", "Value", 
                    RemapValue([[1,9],[2,8],[3,1],[4,6],[5,3],[6,3],[7,1]]))
outReclass1.save("C:/sapyexamples/output/landuse_rcls")

outReclass2 = Reclassify("slope_grd", "Value", 
                     RemapRange([[0,10,"NODATA"],[10,20,1],[20,30,2],
                                 [30,40,3],[40,50,4],[50,60,5],[60,75,6]]))
outReclass2.save("C:/sapyexamples/output/slope_rcls")

outReclass3 = Reclassify("pop_density", "Value", 
                     RemapRange([[10,10,1],[10,20,2],[20,25,3],
                                 [25,50,4],[50,]]), "NODATA")
outReclass3.save("C:/sapyexamples/output/popden_rcls")
```

Comment: Thank you @whyzar for your help!  What happens to the values that I want to keep them as they are without reclassification?

Comment: Reclassify worked. However, I think for ArcGIS Pro the above syntax did not work or maybe because I am using arcpy. I had to use arcpy.reclassify_3d (InputRaster, field, "from  to  new value;from  to  new value", Output). Sorry I am still a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I added this solution before the ArcGIS Pro tag, but here's a GDAL/Numpy solution:

You can could use gdal and numpy to reclassify your raster.

First open the file and read as array:

```
arr = gdal.Open("/path/to/your/file").ReadAsArray()
```

Then use numpy to classify certain pixel ranges:

Example:

```
>>> arr = np.random.randint(100, size = (5,5))
>>> arr
array([[30, 74,  6,  4, 94],
       [45, 13, 15,  5, 35],
       [26, 48, 17, 30, 24],
       [56, 24, 19, 11, 39],
       [70, 18, 31, 59, 24]])
>>> arr[arr<50]= 0
>>> arr
array([[ 0, 74,  0,  0, 94],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [56,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [70,  0,  0, 59,  0]])
```

Then write the array back to file:

```
def array2raster(rasterfn,newRasterfn,array):
    raster = gdal.Open(rasterfn)
    geotransform = raster.GetGeoTransform()
    proj = raster.GetProjection()
    originX = geotransform[0]
    originY = geotransform[3]
    pixelWidth = geotransform[1]
    pixelHeight = geotransform[5]
    cols = raster.RasterXSize
    rows = raster.RasterYSize

    driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')
    outRaster = driver.Create(newRasterfn, cols, rows, 1, gdal.GDT_Float32) # Change dtype here
    outRaster.SetGeoTransform((originX, pixelWidth, 0, originY, 0, pixelHeight))
    outband = outRaster.GetRasterBand(1)
    outband.WriteArray(array)

    outRaster.SetProjection(proj)
    outband.FlushCache()

array2raster("/path/to/raster.tif", "/path/to/newraster.tif", array)
```